# get data based on MAX date and customer id

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: customers and contracts. The common key between them is customer_id.  I need to link these two tables to represent if my fictitious business is on contract with a customer.

The customer -> contract table has a one to many relationship, so a customer can have an old contract on record.  I want the latest.  This is currently handled by contract_id which is auto-incremented.

My query is supposed to grab the contract data based on customer_id and the max contract_id for that customer_id.

My query currently looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT co.* 
        FROM contracts co
        LEFT JOIN customers c ON co.customer_id = c.customer_id 
        WHERE co.customer_id ='135') a 
    where a.contract_id = MAX(a.contract_id);
```

The answer is probably ridiculously obvious and I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: dmcoding, i think you have the `LEFT JOIN`  inverted. Should be `Customer LEFT JOIN Contracts` and that mean the relationship is 0 to many ... not 1 to many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the most recent contract will be the one with the highest `a.contract_id`, simply `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT co.* 
        FROM contracts co
        LEFT JOIN customers c ON co.customer_id = c.customer_id 
        WHERE co.customer_id ='135') a 
ORDER BY a.contract_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This will result in 1 record, if you remove the `WHERE` it won't work.

Comment: i was wrong, because you already filtering by user_id. this should work. But remove the outside `SELECT * FROM`

Comment: @sagi, why wouldnt work? I read the question wrong at first. But look like OP only want one a record

Comment: Just sounds suspicious for that need for a specific user, usually people want the queries to be generic. If that's the case, it won't work.. @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: Yep this is exactly what I needed.  Like I said, super easy and just not seeing it.  And as @JuanCarlosOropeza said in another comment I have my 'LEFT JOIN' all messed up, so I needed to fix that as well.  The customer_id was hard coded in for testing purposes.  In reality it's using php to handle what customer is being looked up.

Comment: There's no point in an OUTER JOINed table from which one selects no columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM contracts c
LEFT JOIN customers co
 ON(co.customer_id = c.customer_id)
WHERE co.customer_id = '135'
 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM contracts co2
                WHERE co2.customer_id = co.customer_id
                  AND co2.contract_id > co.contract_id)
```

This will make sure it's the latest contract, it is dynamic for all customers, you can just remove `WHERE co.customer_id = '135'` and you will get all the results.

In general, you can't use an aggregation function on the `WHERE` clause, only on the `HAVING()` which will be usually combined with a `GROUP BY` clause.